# Open a excel file in Microsoft Excel Online from a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a shared xls file in One Drive. Which i want to view though Excel Online.
The Link would be sent to users through mails. The user will open it in browser by clicking it. 
Just like the Google Docs Viewer

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://spreadsheetpage.com/downloads/xl/time%2520sheet.xls
```

But, in Microsoft Excel Online and the file is in One Drive itself.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use WL.api to provide the path of the file stored on onedrive. This function returns a URL if it succeeds. You have to send this link through email. User will be able to view the invoice stored on your onedrive by clicking on this link using excel online.
:-)

Comment: Hey you got that answer